# Scala - type mismatch problem with own type (String) and Future

Tags: scala, future

I have a method, which need `String` type as an argument:

```
type Identity = String
case class RequireSmth(param: Identity) extends Something
```

Now I call this method in more complex order:

```
createMe(as[List])(arg =>{ parse(RequireSmth(getAction(name, surname).map(bool => getData(surname, bool).id))) })
```

`Parse` looks like:

```
def parse(ob: Something)
```

Where:

```
def getAction(name: String, surname: String): Future[Boolean] = {
    someObject.get(name).map(_.getSomething(surname).isPossibleToTake.getOrElse(false)) //someObject is defined in constructor and does not matter here
}

def getData: (String, Boolean) => MyObject = {
    case ("Doe", true) => possible
    case _ => notPossible
}
```

`MyObject`, `possible` and `notPossible` definition:

```
case class MyObject(id : String, name: String, surname: String)

val possible = MyObject( id = "ok", name ="John", surname = "Doe")
val notPossible = MyObject( id = "not ok", name ="John", surname = "Doe")
```

The problem is, when I call `RequireSmth` method I got an error:

```
type mismatch;
found: scala.concurrent.Future[String]
required: com.my.smth.Identity (which expands to) String
```

How can I solve this problem to return `Identity` (or `String`) instead of `Future[String]`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to flip the method calls:

```
val res: Future[???] = 
   getAction(name, surname)
     .map(bool => getData(surname, bool).id)
     .map(RequireSmth)
     .map(parse)
```

Note that `Future[String]` is not a `String`, it's a computation that will yield a value in the future, and that means that the entire computation stack needs to return a `Future[T]` as well (unless you explicitly await, which blocks and is not recommended).

Comment: I edited a little bit my first post. I used your and @Tim solutions, but here I have compilation error on method `parse`: Cannot resolve overloaded method 'parse'

Comment: @allocer What is the signature of `parse`? Where is it coming from?

Comment: From the error you're getting, it looks like `parse` is an overloaded method?

Comment: Yes, the method is more complicated (I edidted again). I solved parse problem with Tim advices. Now I need to flip whole this method I think but I have no idea how.

Comment: @allocer WDYM flip whole this method? What needs flipping?

Comment: This first part I think `createMe(as[List])(arg =>...)`

Answer (score 3):

Keep the information inside the `Future` like this:

```
getAction(name, surname).map(bool => getData(surname, bool).id).map(RequireSmth)
```

---

Just keep chaining the operations together, keeping everything inside the `Future`:

```
getAction(name, surname)
  .map(bool => getData(surname, bool).id)
  .map(RequireSmth) // Or x => RequireSmth(x) if necessary
  .map(parse)
```

At some point you will get to a method that has a side-effect and returns `Unit`, and that will be executed when all the actions in the `Future` are complete.

In the unlikely event that you actually need to get the value out of the `Future`, use `Await.result`. But in most cases this will not be necessary.

Comment: But wiil it return same result type as my solution?

Comment: I edited a little bit my first post. I used your  solution, but here I have compilation error on method parse: Cannot resolve overloaded method 'parse'

Comment: Yes, it looks like it does not return same result type. I need `Something` but got here `RequireSmth`

Comment: Ok, I will try it. What if I can have something like: `create(as[Map])(arg =>parse(RequireSmth(...))`. Is it still possible to do it that way as you shaw?